# How do you make this symbol in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This question is as simple as it gets. There's a symbol used for certain polynomials in my area of expertise that I'm completely unfamiliar with, and I'm not sure how to look up the code for the symbol, so I figured I'd ask here.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), I immediately found it:

> \usepackage{amssymb}
>
> \mathfrak{S}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image: mathfrak]

Comment: Thanks. I guess if you open your mind it kind of looks like an S. I've seen mathfrak used before but only for a few letters.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm sorry if I hurt you. I just wanted to indicate an online way to solve this kind of problem.